# How to use imacros inside html file

Tags: imacros

How can I correctly use Imacros in JS file? I added a macros script to bookmarks and took location and put inside the JS file,but it seems that its not working. What is the cause why its not working?

I used this command.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros:/\/run/?m=%23Current.iim;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to run Imacros from HTML file.

1. Add imacros to bookmarks.
2. Click property, copy location link.
3. In Html file between `<script>`tag put: `window.location.href='imacros://run/?m=%23Current.iim';`

Answer (score 0):

Refer the URL http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay() , you need to specify like this

```
iimPlay ("c:\MyMacros\macro1.iim")
```